# Many GDI Objects on CreatePopupMenu

Tags: winforms, winapi, menu, gdi

I am creating menus using CreatePopupMenu and my GDI objects hold around the 1500 range but increase when the menu is showing. Now on the task bar in XP and up you can create a tool bar associated with a directory then navigate this directory in a menu. I am guessing they are creating the menus the same way however explorer's GDI objects never increase as the menu is navigated.

Any ideas on what they are doing that I may not be? Are they creating the menu the same way I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XP Startmenu (All programs)  and deskband "overflow" menus are actually toolbar windows, not HMENU's. I'm also guessing that they are using the shared image list for icons and the sys color brushes for the rest, so no new GDI objects are actually created.